# Google business listing logo issue

Tags: seo, google, local-seo, google-my-business

Not displaying uploaded logo in google business listing, currently listing picture from blog, blog picture etc..
any idea to resolve this issue ?

Comment: The answer fully depends on the search query and the result of course. Can you give us  the search query and a screen shot of what you see? Various results come from either the knowledge graph or the regular index. Knowing what you see and how you got the results will allow for a precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean the image which gets displayed next to map in Google My Business?

Or issue in Google Plus?

Regardless of the situation, firstly make sure you got admin access to your Google My Business / G+ access.

Generally, in Google my business it fetches the image from G+ banner image or related.

Also, you should be able to change profile photo easily using the logo.

Note: Mare sure you got images in right resolution.

If this doesn't help, you may need to explain slightly more in detail.

Hope this helps.

Comment: tanks for your help, Not google plus, about Google My Business, i have access Google My Business / G+ access. right resolution means ?

Comment: Right resolution means, if the image might be too small then it may not pick the image you would like to see. So, have good size image.